Which (probably sci-fi) movie end credits with gradually darkening alien landscape artwork throughout?
What I vaguely remember is that there is beautiful artwork of something like an alien planet terrain, on the sides of the screen (probably scrolling) with the credit text in between, and I think the alien landscapes gradually change, and I believe become darker. They last either the whole duration or nearly that of the whole end credits.
Probably a late 90s through 00s movie, before 2010s. Either streaming or on region 1 DVD, and English language.

There's not a lot to go on here.

@Valorum yeah, that's why this has been very difficult to solve! I don't think a lot of movies have artwork throughout the entire end credits, but there are surprisingly few resources for finding those that do…

@WorldofDepth can you recall if it was animated or live action, what language it was in , di you watch it on TV or in the cinema??? was it a US production, european, asian? there will be lots of info you can give us if you think about take a look at the question guidelines here...https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour

Thanks, @skyjack—added a few more details.
